# Keep window in foreground (even if it loses focus)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, dialog, foreground

In my application (C#, Windows Forms) I have got a telephone information screen: if there is an incoming phone call a window with additional information to the caller is shown.

This window should open in foreground and should stay there even if the user is writing in another window (so the user still sees the information regarding the incoming phone call).

First I've used BringToFront - but this didn't really work in all circumstances (e.g. when the main application was not in the foreground).

Right now I am using BringToFront and the user32.dll function BringWindowToTop -> which works, but if the window loses focus it is in the background.

How do I implement this behaviour ?

Comment: And Raymond Chen likes to point out: Sometimes you can't. What if two programs did this?

Comment: Good quote - but quite a bit overused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want to set your form as [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx):

```
yourForm.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: TopMost: Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a window appears in the topmost z-order. So nope, that ain't it, when you want the form to stay on top when you lose focus.

Comment: @tzup: toss together a little sample project and try it out. You're in for a surprise...

Comment: @CMS, you're right ... darn it ... I think I read that question too fast. That ought to teach me!