# How can we make a Jframe blink like skype message in taksbar?

Tags: java

When we get message in Skype the icon in taskbar blink till we open that window.

I have tried method like `toFront()` but nothing working in my case.

Comment: Well, it can't be done from within Java, you need to find a native based solution

Comment: Possible duplicate [Make JFace Window blink in taskbar or get users attention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773364/make-jface-window-blink-in-taskbar-or-get-users-attention)

Comment: [JNIWrapper and WinPack](https://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper) may also be able to do it

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i was looking for doing it by WinPack will be quite impossible

Comment: Well, you're kind of stuck them - the operation you're talking about it is OS specific and not supported by Java :/