# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetForegroundWindow()

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

Currently we are developing a Eclipse RCP application. I am using the method

> OS.GetForegroundWindow()

for getting the foreground window. 
When I locally running the application it is working fine. But when we are running the same application after making a build it gives the following error.(maven tycho build)

**Error:**

```
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 2 2018-04-03 12:31:22.074
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetForegroundWindow()
```

Please let me know if any one have solution. Or if there is any alternate approach we can use instead of **OS.GetForegroundWindow()** .

Have found some related references info in [Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=192036)

StackoverFlow reference link : [Stackoverflow Ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315560/how-do-you-force-a-java-swt-program-to-move-itself-to-the-foreground)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution for making your shell on top, it is working on window 7

```
public static void forceActive(final Shell shell) {
    shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            shell.forceActive();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. It is working in both windows 7 and 10.